# For JMS, how to access topic name in Java code?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I am using `ActiveMQ` which uses `JMS`. I have a requirement where I need to find the topic name from Java program. Is there any `JMS` api for that?

EDIT: There is an api in `JMS` to find topic but will it work for `ActiveMQ` topics?

Comment: Question for the EDIT part ... Which is that API of JMS that your found which helps you find the topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do that (choosing one depends on your use case).

A possibility for ActiveMQ is

```
org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.BrokerViewMBean.getTopics()
```